# Pass form values to the next request

Tags: python, flask, request, pymongo, gevent

So, I did some benchmarks to see how many requests the app could handle. It turns out that when a database operation is involved, no more than 500-560 requests/sec can be handled before timing out subsequent requests, whereas without the database layer it easily comes to a whopping 1000-1100 requests/sec.

I still didn't manage to cut the db costs in most of the pages (and I'm working on it), but there's one where this overhead can be cut: the **edit** page.

I have the following view which is executed when you visit **http://website.com/edit**. What it does is get the **id** parameter in the url and find the post from the db (MongoDB) with it, which then pass the iterated output to the template:

```
def edit(id):
  item = mongo.db.documents.find_one({'_id': id})
  doc = item.iteritems()
  return render_template('edit.html',
                          content=item[0],
                          title=item[3],
                          url=item[2],
                          id=post[1]
                         )
```

This code is executed when you click edit in the item page, which is made like this:

```
{% block body %}

  <a href="/doc/{{ url }}/">{{ title }}</a>

    <p>{{ content }}</p>

<div>
<a href=delete>Delete</a>
<a href=edit>Edit</a>
</div>

<form method="post" action="/post">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ id }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{ url }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ title }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="content" value="{{ content }}" />

      <div>
        <h5>Your Name :</h5>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="add_comment_author" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <h5>Your Thought :</h5>
          <textarea name="content id="add_comment_content"></textarea>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see there are already hidden inputs with the needed value, but they're used for the comments.

Is it possible to do something like this?:

```
def edit(id):
  #item = mongo.db.documents.find_one({'_id': id})
  #doc = item.iteritems()

  doc = request.get.previous()
  return render_template('edit.html',
                          content=doc[0],
                          title=doc[3],
                          url=doc[2],
                          id=doc[1]
                         )
```

Alternatively would it be possible to have two **POST** in one page (one for sending a comment, the other for sending the values to the edit page?

Or maybe use Flash? But I suspect that's highly suboptimal and prone to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Typical solution is to use a caching layer like [Flask-Cache](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) and a memcached server to cache recently accessed data.

Having an edit form in the page is good. You can have as many forms as you want. Btw the common approach is to have only some sort of "templated" forms hidden that you'll then fill using jQuery os similar JS libraries.

In your example you're also passing the `content` field as hidden. Why? One might modify your source and change the content. :)